# First time getting this message 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I'm a beginner and this is my first receiving this message "IndexError: list index out of range," can someone please tell me how to fix it? and what exactly did I do wrong? Also if someone can run it and make sure it does what it's supposed to because I need another person other than me to run it(Professor's instruction)**

This is the output it gave me -

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 74, in 
File "", line 24, in user
IndexError: list index out of range**

Here's my code:

```
print ("Dish No.      Dish Name       Price ")
print (" --------     ---------      ------")
print ("    1         Gang Gai        $10.00")
print ("    2         Pad Thai        $8.75")
print ("    3         Pad Cashew      $9.50")
print ("    4         Pad Prik        $10.25")
print ("    5         Peanut Curry    $9.50")
print ("    6         Curry Noodles   $11.25")  


def user():
    array = [10,8.75,9.50,10.25,9.50,11.25]
    cart = []
    while True:
        x = int(input("Enter the item number you want (1-6):"))
        check = checker(x)
        if check == "wrong number":
            print("Enter a valid number")
            pass
        cart.append(array[x-1])
    
        xx=input("Would you like to order another item( Yes or No)?: ")
        if xx.lower() == "no":
            break
       
    
    checkout(cart)    
    # if xx=='No'.lower():
    #     return array[x-1]
    # else:
    #     return array[x-1]+user(array) 
    
def seniorCitizen():
    print("Are you 65 years or older(Yes or No)? ")
    xsenior = input()
    if xsenior.lower() == "yes":
        senior = True
    else:
        senior = False
    return senior
    
    
def checker(num):
    if num > 6 or num < 1:
        return "wrong number"
    
    
def checkout(cart):
    senior = seniorCitizen()
    titems = 0
    for item in cart:
        titems = titems + item
        
    print("        Bill Information       ")
    print("-------------------------------")
    print("Total of all items:     $",titems)
    if senior == True:
        boomercount = titems * 0.1
        boomercount = round(boomercount, 2)
        print("Total senior discounts:-$", boomercount)
        tax = round((titems-boomercount)*0.06, 2)
        print("Taxes:                  $",tax)
        print("                Bill:   $",  round(((titems-boomercount)+tax), 2))
    else:
        tax = round(titems*0.06, 2)
        print("Taxes:                  $",tax)
        print("                Bill:   $",  round((titems+tax), 2))

    
user()
```

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.  Also show us the input you gave to the program.

Comment: When `x > 6`, `array[x-1]` will be out of range since it only has 6 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    x = int(input("Enter the item number you want (1-6):"))
    check = checker(x)
    if check == "wrong number":
        print("Enter a valid number")
        pass
    cart.append(array[x-1])
```

The problem is the `pass` statement.  It does *not* restart the loop -- it does *nothing at all*.  So if the user enters a wrong number, it prints an error message but then it keeps going and tries to access `array[x-1]` which is out of range.

Use `continue` which will start the loop over, instead of `pass`.